# Angular Arrays not outputting to screen

Tags: angularjs

I created an object called reveiws and I'm trying to get it to appear on the screen. When I put ng-repeat="rev in reviews" in div id reviews nothing appears at all on the screen. It's blank except for the word Hello. Also there are no console errors. If I remove that line `ng-repeat="rev in reviews"`and keep it as `<div id="reviews" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">`
Then it appears as

```
Hello
{{rev.name}} {{"HI"}}
```

so the code is only affected in the controller since Hello, which is outside of the controller outputted correctly. Why is the array not outputting the name?

index.html

```
<html ng-app="objectTest" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  {{"Hello"}}

  <div id="reviews" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl" ng-repeat="rev in reviews">
    {{rev.name}} {{"HI"}}
  </div><script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script src="app.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('objectTest', [])
    .controller('mainController'['$scope' , function($scope){
    $scope.reviews = [
    {
    name: "Joe Smith",
    description: "It works!"

    },
{
  name: "Bill Smith",
 description: "great site"
}
    ];


    }]);
```

Comment: You're missing a comma between 'mainController' and ['$scope...... so you can check your dev. tools console and see an error, you don't have any controller registered

Comment: $scope.reviews is indeed an array, but that actually works since you use ng-repeat to loop over this array.

Comment: You will need to split the ng-controller div from the ng-repeat div, as ng-repeat runs first, your reviews variable will not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you remove the "as" syntax when you define the controller in the view.

Change `ng-controller="mainController as ctrl"` to `ng-controller="mainController"`.

**Updated:** added working code

```js
var app = angular.module('objectTest', [])
    .controller('mainController', ['$scope' , function($scope){
    $scope.reviews = [
    {
    name: "Joe Smith",
    description: "It works!"

    },
{
  name: "Bill Smith",
 description: "great site"
}
    ];


    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="objectTest" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div ng-repeat="rev in reviews">
    {{ rev.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it to  <div id="reviews" ng-controller="mainController" ng-repeat="rev in reviews">
    {{rev.name}} {{"HI"}} and the page is still blank

Comment: have you corrected the missing comma in your controller declaration?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you did differently from me so I don't make the mistake again. Did I just have a syntax error somewhere? I saw the comma you were talking about, but I fixed that already

Comment: you mixed 2 different ways of declaring controllers in angular, 1. using `controller as` syntax and 2. using $scope. If you use the first, then you can binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using `this`, while the latter, you attach these properties and methods to `$scope`.

Comment: Does it matter putting the ng-repeat in it's own div like you did or could I technically put ng-controller in the same div as ng-repeat?

Comment: It seemed to work after I separated the two like you did

Comment: so if you use `controller as`, then in your controller, you have to do this `this.reviews = [{}, {}]` instead of `$scope.reviews = [{}, {}]`

Comment: As @Noppey have mentioned, in this scenario if you put 'ng-controller' and 'ng-repeat' in the same element, your 'reviews' array is not yet created. But technically, you could put ng-controller in the same element with ng-repeat but just remember that you're creating a controller instance for every clone that gets created in the ngRepeat loop.